# Display contrast change when playing media

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, display, color

I have a weird issue with my MacBook Pro that I bought about 3 weeks ago.

I noticed that when I start playing VLC player or even when opening up certain websites that the color saturation seems to automatically change on the machine. I don't think that this is related to the "automatically adjust brightness" in the system preferences because I disabled that and the issue remains.

Does anyone know why the color saturation seems to change when I start playing media? For example, the grey at the top of windows seems to change to a very pale blue.

Comment: I have the same issue! But it’s not just when playing media. It happens with any dark colour. After I move my mouse over said colour or scroll a page, the blacks lose some saturation. This is very localised to only the dark colours, like the black bar over this page.

Comment: Does it do this when the graphics card switches? (Use gfxCardStatus to see when that happens.)